# How can I apply changes to the web after the POST method?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Any changes that I want does not take effect because the page refreshes itself whenever I click a button.

With the POST method on it. This the scenario, I clicked the button, then changes take effect like editing the inner html of a division, after that, the page refreshes itself that is why all the changes disappears. Please help me if there are any ways that changes can be made after the page refreshes.

This is my code. Can you tell me how to use ajax on it?

```
<form name="myForm" method="POST">
<button style="border-radius:0px;" type="submit" name="tabExe" id="tabExe" href="#Exec" onClick="myFunction('Executive');" class="btn btn-primary">Executive Room>
</button> 
</form> 
<script> 
 function myFunction(str){ 
   if(document.getElementById(str) == tabExe){ 
      document.getElementById('room1').innerHTML = "Room 101";  
    } 
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: use ajax for post. Page will not refresh

Comment: this is my code.. can you tell me how to use ajax on it?

<form name="myForm" method="POST">

<button style="border-radius:0px;" type="submit" name="tabExe" id="tabExe" href="#Exec" onClick="myFunction('Executive');" class="btn btn-primary">Executive Room</button>
</form>

<script>
function myFunction(str){ 
                   if(document.getElementById(str) == tabExe){
            document.getElementById('room1').innerHTML = "Room 101";  
    }

  }


</script>

Comment: for your reference [LINK](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp)

Answer (score 0):

When u clicked on submit button . form submitted. But when u use button as type, It will not refresh.

remove `type ="submit"`. use type `type ="button"`

add **`return false`**; in onclick function. So it change bydefault property.

```
<form name="myForm" method="POST">
  <button style="border-radius:0px;" name="tabExe" id="tabExe" href="#Exec" 
        onClick="myFunction('Executive'); return false;" class="btn btn-primary">
    Executive Room>
   </button> 
</form> 

   <script> 
     function myFunction(str){ 
        alert();
       if(document.getElementById(str) == tabExe){ 
          document.getElementById('room1').innerHTML = "Room 101";  
        } 

      }   
    </script>
```

Comment: But i need the value of that ID and pass it to my php so I really need to use POST

Comment: @RolandMendoza  use this `document.getElementById(str).value()`

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code of Javascript ajax as you need:

```
function submit()
{
  var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhReq.open("POST", "yourpage.phtml?param1=2&param2=10", false);
  xhReq.send(null);
  var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
  alert(serverResponse);
  return false;
}
```

HTML onsubmit method:

```
<form name="myForm" method="POST" onsubmit="return submit()">
```

Comment: in what part of that code should I put this document.getElementById('room1').innerHTML = "Room 101";

Comment: I believe you are talking about param(Parameters)